# Setting deveexpress grid focusedrow ndex via javascript based on key field value

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am trying to set focused row index of devexpress grid via javascript,currently i am doing in callback,but i dont want it to do in callback.My code is below,

```
function OnbtnOkClick(s, e) {
    gvEmpSearch.GetRowValues(gvEmpSearch.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'employeeId;LastName;FirstName', OnGetRowValues);
    popCtrlEmpSearch.Hide();
}
//performs callback and sets the focused row index
function OnGetRowValues(values) {
    var empId = Object(values[0]);
    gvEmp.PerformCallback(empId);
```

//i want to set here the focusedrow index rather than doing callback and setting
    }

Callback Method of the grid

```
Protected Sub gvEmployee_CustomCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs) Handles gvEmployee.CustomCallback

    'gets the key value from employee search sets the focused row based on that
    Dim keyValue As Integer = CInt(e.Parameters)
    gvEmployee.FocusedRowIndex = gvEmployee.FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue(keyValue)
    gvEmployee.DetailRows.ExpandRowByKey(keyValue)

End Sub
```

Any Idea ?

Thanks in advance

Arasu

Answer (score 2):

On server side set grid `ClientInstanceName` property. Then, on client side use

```
clientInstanceNameValue.SetFocusedRowIndex(index)
```

Doc: [ASPxClientGridView.SetFocusedRowIndex](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_SetFocusedRowIndextopic)

EDIT: 
You could iterate through rows on grid page and use [GetRowKey](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_GetRowKeytopic) to determine if your key value equals row key value. But that will work only for visible rows (on current grid page). If your row isn't visible you will have to use callback or [client side data caching](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E123.aspx) (depending on grid total row count).

Comment: ya that i know...the problem is how to find the visible row index of a grid by key value.In code behind we have FindVisibleRowIndeByKeyValue () method but we can do this in javascript this only i want to know...